# Finding the limit at positive and negative infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$$y = (3-x)(1+x)^2(1-x)^4$$

Hello,

how can I find the limit when $x \to \infty$ and when $x \to - \infty$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for $x\rightarrow +\infty$ you can say that
$$y=(3-x)(1+x)^2(1-x)4 \sim (-x)(x)^2(-x)^4=-x^7\longrightarrow -\infty\mbox,$$
similarli for $x\rightarrow -\infty$
$$y\sim -x^7 \longrightarrow +\infty\mbox.$$